# Insert new line after last occurence of string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, newline

I'm trying to add a new line after the last occurence of a string in bash.

For example, if I had the following text:

```
GG1 test-35
GG1 test-38
GG1 test-40

HH1 test-52
HH1 test-60
HH1 test-32
HH1 test-40

LL1 test-101
LL1 test-99
LL1 test-24
```

Say I wanted to add a new line at the end of the 'HH' block, so it'd become:

```
HH1 test-52
HH1 test-60
HH1 test-32
HH1 test-40
HH1 test-56
```

So far I've tried using sed and awk but can't seem to get it right. It's simple to do if I could search for an actual test number, like HH1 test-40, but the only thing I can search for is the acronym. So I'd need the last line occurrence of HH1, and then add a new line after it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: did you want to print only the HH1 block or the whole file?

Comment: The whole file, it'd just have the new included line of HH1 test-56

Comment: What is the input ? `test-56` to add to block XX or directly `HH1 test-56` to add to a block (or create a new block)

Answer (score 3):

quick & dirty with gawk:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}/^HH/{$0=$0"\nHH1 test-56"}7' file
```

it's dirty because it leaves an empty line at the end of output.

Comment: it won't work if the last `HH1` is not followed by a blank line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP said `HH block`. my solution came from my understanding of the question and OP's example.

Comment: i think he means the HH block for the example only. See the first line "I'm trying to add a new line after the last occurence of a string in bash."

Comment: @AvinashRaj `I wanted to add a new line at the end of the 'HH' block,` also OP's "answer(deleted)":`that worked like a charm!` . Anyway, if OP data is like what you assumed, you are right ,my one-liner won't work. process the file twice (or save file in mem) would fix it. very easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone! Yeah sorry for not being clearer, Kent's solution is working as I want! I was wondering if you could help me with one further issue. I'm wanting to pass in shell variables to replace "HH" and "HH1 test 56" in the example above, and not having much luck again!

Comment: @user3722194 `awk -v block="$block" -v newline="$newline" 'BEGIN{...} $0~block{$0=$0 "\n" newline}7'` something like this, then you can pass shell var `$block and $newline`  in.

Comment: Great! I was trying to pass in the shell variables incorrectly. Your solution works again, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There's a LOT of options:

```
awk '/HH/{seen++} seen && !/HH/{print "HH1 test-56"; seen=0} 1' file
```

or:

```
tac file | awk '/HH/ && !seen{print "HH1 test-56"; seen++} 1' | tac
```

or:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/HH/) nr=NR; next} 1; FNR==nr{print "HH1 test-56"}' file file
```

or (gawk-only for multi-char RS):

```
gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{sub(/.*HH[^\n]+\n/,"&HH1 test-56\n")} 1' file
```

or....

Answer (score 1):

One more awk 
Should work in all awks

```
awk 'a=/^HH/{b=1}b&&!a{print "HH1 test-56";b=0}1' file
```

or

```
awk -F- 'a=/HH/{b=$1}b&&!a{print b"-56";b=0}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed '/^HH1/!b;:a;n;//ba;i\HH1 test-56' file
```

If the line doesn't begin `HH1` print as normal, otherwise print until the line doesn't begin `HH1` and then insert a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
LineToAdd="HH1 test-56"
{ echo "${LineToAdd}"; cat YourFile; } | sed -n '1x;H;${x
   s/^\([^ ]\{3\}\) \([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)\1 \([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\3/\4\1 \5\3\1 \2\3/
   s/^\n//
   p
   }'
```

**Explain**

- add line to add at start of content (could be done by adding at end, some code to addapt)
- load all line in buffer
- move (sustitute by rewrinting group place) the 2 group of first line (so group 1 as HH1 and test-56 as group 2) after the latest line having group 1. (here is quick and dirty assuming there is no HH1 in following content of one line)
- remove first line if new line (quick and dirty also, assuming original file does not start with new line)
- print the result
  -

Answer (score 0):

The below perl command would add a new line  after the last `HH1` line,

```
perl -0777pe 's/(?s)(?<=HH1\stest-)(\d+\n)(?=(?:(?!HH1\stest-).)*$)/\1HH1 test-56\n/' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
HH1 test-52
HH1 test-60
HH1 test-32

LL1 test-101
LL1 test-99
HH1 test-40
LL1 test-24
```

---

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/(?s)(?<=HH1\stest-)(\d+\n)(?=(?:(?!HH1\stest-).)*$)/\1HH1 test-56\n/' file
HH1 test-52
HH1 test-60
HH1 test-32

LL1 test-101
LL1 test-99
HH1 test-40
HH1 test-56
LL1 test-24
```

Answer (score 0):

A small bash script can also provide the flexibility and string addition you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Usage:
#
# ./scriptname datafile [new-sting-to-add (HH1 test-56)] [string-to-search (HH1)]

newstr="${2:-HH1 test-56}"          # set newstr
srchstr="${3:-"${newstr// */}"}"    # set srchstr
found=1                             # set found flag to false

# read datafile line-by-line
while read pfx tststr || [ -n "$tststr" ] ; do
    [ "$pfx" == "$srchstr" ] && found=0                 # if pfx matches set flag
    [ $found -eq 0 ] && [ "$pfx" != "$srchstr" ] && {   # if flag and no match
        echo "$newstr"                                  # add newstr to output
        found=1                                         # reset flag to false
    }
    echo "$pfx $tststr"             # normal output

done <"$1"
```

**output:**

```
$ ./hh.sh dat/hh.dat    # (using default values)
GG1 test-35
GG1 test-38
GG1 test-40

HH1 test-52
HH1 test-60
HH1 test-32
HH1 test-40
HH1 test-56

LL1 test-101
LL1 test-99
LL1 test-24
```